Hyperledger explorer and AWS Managed Blockchain connection
I want to connect my hyper ledger explorer that would run locally to the AWS-managed blockchain network. What are the steps to do this? I already have my AWS configured locally for CLI.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8r0P0uLhvKU
I have followed the above link but what are the next steps what changes to make in first-network.json/test-network.json
{
  "name": "first-network",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "client": {
    "tlsEnable": true,
    "adminCredential": {
      "id": "tracelyfe",
      "password": "rtpl"
    },
    "enableAuthentication": false,
    "organization": "Org1MSP",
    "connection": {
      "timeout": {
        "peer": {
          "endorser": "300"
        },
        "orderer": "300"
      }
    }
  },
  "channels": {
    "mychannel": {
      "peers": {
        "peer0.org1.example.com": {}
      },
      "connection": {
        "timeout": {
          "peer": {
            "endorser": "6000",
            "eventHub": "6000",
            "eventReg": "6000"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "organizations": {
    "Org1MSP": {
      "mspid": "Org1MSP",
      "adminPrivateKey": {
        "path": "/tmp/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp/keystore/priv_sk"
      },
      "peers": ["peer0.org2.example.com"],
      "signedCert": {
        "path": "/tmp/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@org2.example.com-cert.pem"
      }
    }
  },
  "peers": {
    "peer0.org1.example.com": {
      "tlsCACerts": {
        "path": "/tmp/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
      },
      "url": "grpcs://peer0.org2.example.com:7051"
    }
  }
}



What configuration needs to be replaced with what?
And what are the changes required as https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8r0P0uLhvKU was for the private network?

